# How to extract only few classes from darknet model

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, yolo

Maybe this question is weird or I don't know for what to ask... But I need to extract only few classes from whole weight file yolov3.weights model.

I don't need to get predictions for all classes, but only few. For example: Car, Truck, Bus, Person and that's all. I think it can speed up prediction process.

At this moment in my code I'm simply detecting everything on image, but marking with OpenCV only objects from above list.

Do I need to train my own model or there is simplier way? I don't have any datasets available, and it can be hard to create some as I'm quite under time pressure.

Comment: it can't really speedup prediction process. Understand neural networks and that specific architecture and see where the processing load is present. You CAN speed it up by using a smaller architecture and train it only for those classes (you can still use COCO dataaet).

Comment: Maybe I can take COCO dataset and remove unnecessary data from it?
Do you know any tutorial how to train model based on COCO dataset with reduced classes?

Comment: there is no unnecessary data, since you can use images without your needed objects as "negative samples" to reduce false positive detections. Reducing your model complexity is not about removing or adding data (this will just influence the detection quality), but about reducing the architecture (number of layers). You'll probably need some knowledge in deep learning and best to understand the yolo approach to do this successfully.

Comment: Yes. You have right. My knowledge isnt't very big. But I understand what you are talking about :)
When I was thinking about "removing data" I was thinking about reducing number of classes. And Yes. Then I should redesign layers in model. At least last ones (I think, like in transfer learning).

Comment: there is not so much processing load in the last layer(s), that's why just reducing the number of classes on the output side won't help you much. But if you need only 10% the number of classes, maybe you easily reduce the number of filters in each and every layer by 50% and still get a good accuracy (and 100% speedup?) after training?

Comment: Just answering to second this answer from @Micka, there probably won't be a significant speedup, he's right.